# Applying special effects to the selected filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I’m using the quicksand jquery filter. now I want to add a particular effect (which I’ve typed in javascript) to all the images when any of the filters are selected. The filter list is as follows:-

```
<ul class="filter"> 
   <li class="current all"><a href="#">Fred</a></li> 
   <li class="daisy"><a href="#">daisy</a></li> 
   <li class="richard"><a href="#">richard</a></li> 
   <li class="ama"><a href="#">ama</a></li> 
   <li class="santy"><a href="#">santy</a></li> 
   <li class="washington"><a href="#">washington</a></li> 
   <li class="deuces"><a href="#">deuces</a></li> 
</ul>
```

So I’m using the following syntax to determine the selected filter and work some jquery 'magic' from there.

```
    $(".filter a").click(function(e){

    $(".filter li").removeClass("current"); 

    // Get the class attribute value of the clicked link
    var $filterClass = $(this).parent().attr("class");

    if ( $filterClass == "all" ) {
        var $filteredPortfolio = $portfolioClone.find("li");
    } else {
        var $filteredPortfolio = $portfolioClone.find("li[data-type~=" + $filterClass + "]");
        $filteredPortfolio.addClass("row3");
    }
```

Now to add the special effect to the all the images of the selected filter (say photography), I added this code `$("$filteredPortfolio").addClass("row3")` which you see on the last line basically because the effect works on all elements with the class `row3` yet when I debug this in my browser, it fails to work. What am I doing wrong? I still consider myself a jquery newbie so please pardon me if the answer is obvious.

Comment: I would look into [`$.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and this is probably what you mean for the last line in the `else`: `$filteredPortfolio.addClass("row3");` That should be a jQuery object result from `$.find()` on the line above.

Comment: thanks Jared. But the effect is still not been applied to the filtered images. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: What's contained in `$portfolioClone` we have no idea; it's not shown. In other words, what you've provided isn't enough to figure out what's wrong, since things are referenced but not depicted above.

Comment: Ok so I want to find the class of the the image file and I'm using this $(".portfolio a").find("img").attr("class") then I'll add the class "row3" to it if it doesn't have this class. how do I achieve this?

Comment: What you say is the right way to get the class attribute.  To add a new class call .addClass('row3').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last line should be:

```
$filteredPortfolio.addClass("row3");
```

.find() is alrady producing a jQuery object, so there's no need for the extra $()

You are filtering on `[data-type=..]`, which is fine if there is a data-type attribute defined in HTML, but won't work if you are setting it via the .data('type', val) jQuery api.  For the filter to find it, you must use .attr('data-type', val).  Newer versions of jQuery better differentiate between data and attributes, which are actually separate things.  jQuery used to conflate them and using them interchangeably might have worked in an older version.

Comment: Update with explanation of another potential problem.  Post the whole thing on jsfiddle and I can figure it out for sure.

Comment: Ok so I want to find the class of the the image file and I'm using this $(".portfolio a").find("img").attr("class") then I'll add the class "row3" to it if it doesn't have this class. how do I achieve this?

Comment: I think: $(".portfolio a img').not('.row3').addClass('row3')